# React How to set an element's ref value using a variable

Tags: reactjs

So I have something very simple:

```
<TextField ref={id}/>
```

I am wondering how I would use a variable as a ref, instead of a string? I kind of need this because this element is being generated in the render method, just before the return method. So I am using refs that are just created in a for loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<TextField ref={(ref) => this.myRefName = ref} />
```

Then you can access it via `this.myRefName` ie `console.log(this.myRefName)`

Comment: How do you assign the "myRefName" to become a variable? If I try to use "this.i" (i is from the for loop), and I log out "this", I can only see 1 reference to i. How would I dynamically create different refnames?, i.e. ref1, ref2, ref3, without typing it out?

Comment: You can make use of bracket notation and es6 template string, example:

`<TextField ref={(ref) => this[\`ref${i}\`] = ref} />`

Comment: Just what I needed

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `ref callback` to access ref via a variable rather than a string

```
<TextField ref={(input) => this.myField = input}/>
```

Now you can refer to `TextField` like `this.myField`

Ref callback **[doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)**

Comment: How do you assign the "myRefName" to become a variable? If I try to use "this.i" (i is from the for loop), and I log out "this", I can only see 1 reference to i. How would I dynamically create different refnames?, i.e. ref1, ref2, ref3, without typing it out?